# Error when trying to get data from Yahoo via pandas_datareader

Tags: pandas, pandas-datareader

I have problem exciting the simplest code in pandas datareader here is the code:

```
import datetime as dt
import pandas_datareader as web

symbol = "FB"
start = dt.datetime(2020,1,1)
end = dt.datetime(2022,1,1)

df = web.Datareader(symbol, "yahoo", start,end)
```

Error : TypeError : string indices must be integers

Comment: Fixed your title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pandas_datareader no longer works for yahoo.
Try yfinance :

```
import yfinance as yf
symbol = "META"
start = dt.datetime(2020,1,1)
end = dt.datetime(2022,1,1)
df = yf.download(symbol, start = start, end=end)
```

Comment: YF has some rudimentary crypto info. You can use my tessa library to get access to both stock and crypto info via yfinance and pycoingecko respectively. → https://github.com/ymyke/tessa